# Cypress: asserting if the text is found X number of times on a page

Tags: javascript, cypress, functional-testing

I am writing functional tests for my JavaScript web application. I don't have much experience writing tests using Cypress to be honest. What I am trying to test now is that if the user can see a particular text message on the page for the X number of times.

This is my assertion in the test at the moment.

```
cy.contains('Hello World').should('be.visible')
```

As you can see, I am testing that if the "Hello World" message is visible to the user. What I would like to also test is that I want to test if the message is seen for 3 times. How can I do that?

Following is my dummy HTML.

```
<form>

<div>
  <div>
  <input name="email" />
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>This is required.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <input name="password" />
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>This is required.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Does all 3 occurrences of the text "Hello World" appear by using a single selector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each()` ([Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each)) to iterate through the elements and check for the text and also check the length like this. `$list` will contain the no of occurrences of element.

```
cy.get('ul > li').each(($ele, $list) => {
    expect($ele).to.have.text('Hello World')
}).then(($list) => {
    expect($lis).to.have.length(3)
})
```

Comment: Finally, it works referencing on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
cy.contains('Hello World')
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', 3)
```

but this might be a bit fragile, because `.contains()` works on child elements as well. Might be better to be more specific - can you show what HTML you are working with?

---

To search a list, verify the count of `<li>` containing "This is required"

```
cy.get('li:contains("This is required")')
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', 2)
```

See [docs - contains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Yields)

> **Yields**
> .contains() yields the new DOM element it found.

which means Cypress always returns just one element, so we need to move the `contains()` into the selector to get an accurate count.

It's always useful to check the **Yields** paragraph, some commands yield multiple elements and some yield just the first even when multiple match the selector.

Note this will ignore any `<li>` with different text.

Comment: Hello. I tried this. Even thought, the page has two 3 messages, in the test, it is only assuming that it has 1 message. Therefore, the test is failing.

Comment: But you need to be more specific in the selector. Show the HTML, can make suggestion.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the dummy HTML. Please, have a look.